# Powershell equivalent to netsh set hostednetwork?

Tags: powershell

I have some old bat scripts that create a hosted network, and i wanted to replace them with a single powershell script that can create, stop and report the status of a self hosted network.

The closest thing i found is [this script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Set-hosted-network-in-adaa6bb4), but it is just a powershell wrapper for netsh.

These are the scripts i am trying to replace
Start:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=DEVOTION_02 key=****
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

Stop

```
netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
```

Comment: *" just a powershell wrapper for netsh"* - What's wrong with that? `netsh` is the tool for the job. Whether you "wrap" it in BAT or in PS1 makes very little difference.

Comment: some research on the following lead me to the [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/set-netadapteradvancedproperty?view=win10-ps)
You can get more information there this may be of help as you can change the network adapter properties and may be able to configure the required options